# Excel programmatically swap activex image

Tags: image, excel, swap, shapes, vba

I want to, in code, swap an image for a different one. Here's what I have now:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Dim Pic As Picture
    Me.Shapes(5).Delete
    Set Pic = Me.Pictures.Insert("C:\Downloads\cards\2h.gif")
End Sub
```

It's working for the most part, except that it keeps deleting the wrong thing. How can I know and control what is in the Shapes array? In other words, when I add a new picture, how do I know it's index in the Shapes array?

Comment: What exactly are you doing? What is `Me` here?

Comment: Me, in this case, is the current worksheet, I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, that is not an ActiveX image.

You can name the picture after you add it:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Dim Pic As Picture
    On Error Resume Next
    Me.Pictures("MyPic").Delete
    On Error Goto 0
    Me.Pictures.Insert("C:\Downloads\cards\2h.gif").Name = "MyPic"
End Sub
```